# How to identify the equation governing harmonic oscillator?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

> A particle is free to move on x-axis in which of the cases the particle will execute oscillation about $x=1$?
>
> $(1)\,\,\,\,\,F=(x-1)$
> $(2)\,\,\,\,\,F=-(x-1)^2$
> $(3)\,\,\,\,\,F=-(x-1)^3$
> $(4)\,\,\,\,\,F=(x-1)^3$

**Here's my work:**
The particle starts motion about $x=1$.
This means that after $x=1$ force will be restoring, means negative and will lead the particle towards x=1
And before x=1 force will be positive, will lead towards $x=1$. Options (2) and (3) show that the force is restoring.
I need guidance.

Comment: What is $F$ supposed to be?

Comment: F is the force that causes the oscillation

Comment: The $x$-component of the force? I think you think it is the magnitude, but then you have no info about its direction,

Comment: The question only makes sense if $F$ is the $x$-component of the force.

Comment: I really don't have any info about the direction...as you can tell the question doesn't say anything about that..still thanks for the help..!

Comment: Good question, I don't think there has been a particular question on this concept here. However, one suggestion is that you try to make the question as general as possible so that t helps maximum people (also prevents it from being closed).

Comment: I'll try to do that whenever I need help.. Thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

Your considerations are correct. The particle is oscillating if the force is negative for $x > 1$ and positive for $x < 1$. However, this is only true for option 3 as can be seen if you plot the force $F(x)$ against $x$.

[image]

Comment: Helped a lot... thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Option 3. I will start off with the example of Hooke's Law which as you know, states
$$ F = - kx \tag{1} .$$
What's important here is that when $x>0$ the force will be directed leftwards, and when $x<0$ the force will pull left (assuming rightwards is positive, of course).

In your case, you want that the force to pull left if $x>1$ and right if $x<1$. Now we can eliminate some options and here is why.

1. Wrong. The force is not restoring. If $x>1$ the force points right, not left. If $x<1$, the force points left, not right. Do note that if there was a negative sign before the expression, it would actually make this a correct option -- it would simply be Hooke's law.
2. Wrong. This force always pulls left for positive and negative $x$. (why? because the $-(x - 1)^2$ term will always be smaller or equal to 0)
3. Correct. For any $x>1$ the force will be negative, thus pull left. For any $x<1$, the force pulls right. You can look at a graph.
4. Same reason as for (1). The force will not be restoring.

Comment: Well explained sir...now it's clear...thanks a lot to all of you guys..

Answer (score 0):

Basically they are trying to make you find the shifted oscillator. Consider,

$$ x(t) = A\cos(\omega t+ \phi) + x_o$$

Double derivative:

$$ \ddot{x} =-A\omega^2 \cos(\omega t+ \phi)$$

Notice,

$$ A\cos(\omega t + \phi) = x(t) - x_o$$

Hence,

$$ \ddot{x} = -\omega^2 ( x(t) - x_o) $$

Now, find the option which looks like the above

[Check here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MozXZAQNxYg&ab_channel=EddieWoo)